# why OR returns True if the first element is True, but ANY still checks all element even if the first element is True

Tags: python

```
>>> 1 or 1/0
1
>>> any([1, 1/0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

I thought any() could also return True as long as it finds the first True element in the iterable, but why it still checks all elements? Won't it lead to a worse runtime?

Comment: The failure is on the creation of the list, before `any` is called

Comment: `any` doesn't even get a chance to check the *first* element here.

Comment: Try `any(f() for f in [lambda: 1, lambda: 1/0])` -- this will work since `1/0` is never called.

Comment: @FHTMitchell nice way to create a thunk in python :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, `any` does short-circuit (only evaluates as much as needed) but as @alfasin said, you're creating the `1/0` error when you try and insert it into a `list`. To show the delayed evaluation, you'd have to do something like what I put in the comments or

```
def itr():
    yield 1
    yield 1/0

any(itr())  # --> True
```

or

```
class ErrorOnBool:
    def __bool__(self):
        raise RuntimeError()


any([1, ErrorOnBool()])   # --> True
```